# Installing Gems separately with version compatibility conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'd like to install 'metric_fu' gem

```
gem 'metric_fu'
```

once I `bundle` I get this

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby_parser":
  In Gemfile:
    metric_fu (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0) x86-mingw32

    brakeman (~> 2.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      ruby_parser (3.2.2)

Could not find gem 'mojombo-chronic (>= 0.3.0) x86-mingw32', which is required
by gem 'metric_fu (>= 0) x86-mingw32', in any of the sources.
```

So in one hand, I want to install `metric_fu` which depends on `ruby_parser` 2, but `brakeman` depends on `ruby_parser` 3

Is there a way to use both of the gems in such a way that `metric_fu` will use `ruby_parser` 2 and `brakeman` will use version 3?

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be gone in the latest version of MetricFu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more old version of brakeman, which uses ruby parser 2 - 1.8.3 or more early. [Here](http://rubygems.org/gems/brakeman/versions)  you can choose the best version.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is really going out of its way to be confusing here. The latest metric_fu actually depends on ruby_parser 3.1.3, and that is only because of [reek](https://rubygems.org/gems/reek) which currently has a dependency on "ruby_parser ~> 3.1.1". If you really wanted to, you could explicitly depend on Brakeman 2.0.0, which is compatible with ruby_parser 3.1.1. But downgrading security tools is generally not a good idea.

The truth is that Bundler is only good for managing dependencies your application needs to *load*. Brakeman does not need to be loaded, it is almost always used as a standalone command line tool. So my recommendation is to not bother having it in your Gemfile. Just `gem install brakeman`.

Alternatively, get reek to update their dependencies. It will help with Ruby 2.0 syntax support.